# How close to a building has a Soyuz landed?

Tags: landing, soyuz-spacecraft, russia, soviet-union

Soyuz capsules are designed to [land onto land](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/2757/26446).  To avoid the small chance of harming people or property, they are usually targeted to land in remote parts of Kazakhstan.  However, some landings aren't perfectly on target (see [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9601/26446) and [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/15262/26446)), and Kazakhstan is not completely empty.

**What is the record for the closest that a Soyuz capsule has come to hitting a building?**  If pictures are available, please add them to your answer.

Comment: How about spent first stages?  Lots of those in china.

Comment: @geoffc: I'm specifically looking for the descent module that the cosmonauts return inside.  Booster stages, orbital module, and service module are not in the scope of this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nothing is quite like spending the evening looking at blurry satellite photos of Kazakhstan.
The landing area of [Soyuz TM-26](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_TM-26) had a relatively crowded landing area, with several probable buildings close to it:

[50.18°N 67.50°E](https://yandex.com/maps/?l=sat&ll=67.501127%2C50.180674&pt=67.5%2C50.18&z=16)

[image]

Wikipedia has the landing coordinates in two-digit decimal degrees, which gives a north-south accuracy of about 1km, and a slightly better east-west resolution. The likely source, however, [spacefacts.de](http://www.spacefacts.de/mission/english/soyuz-tm26.htm), has it in degrees and minutes, which has a slightly worse resolution.

Taking those accuracy problems into account, the flight most likely landed within 1 km of a building.